# Redis Geo - Returns incorrect distance between two places/lat-longs

Tags: mongodb, redis, geolocation, stackexchange.redis, node-redis

I am using Redis Geo to find distance between two place or lat-longs, but when i compare the result with google distance matrix api there is a big difference between the results.

This is my scenario:

Ran the follwing in redis CLI

1. Ran this command

   ```
   GEOADD Sicily 13.349350 38.272273 "Palermo" 15.089875 37.508123 "Catania"
   ```
2. Ran this command

   ```
   GEORADIUS Sicily 13.349350 38.272273 200 km WITHDIST
   ```

Got this result

```
    1) 1) "Palermo"
    2) "0.0001"
    2) 1) "Catania"
    2) "174.8263"
```

Redis says Catania is 174.8263 km away from Palermo.

While using google api to get the distance between these two lat longs, I get a different result:

```
    https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metrics&origins=38.272273,13.349350&destinations=37.508123,15.089875
```

Google says Catania is 233 km away from Palermo.

I also used mongodb's $geonear and the result was similar to redis:

Mongodb says Catania is 174.971 km away from Palermo.

I believe google distance is correct, so can anyone please help me out what I am doing wrong in Redis. Is there any other way to get correct distance as I want to use redis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the difference between the direct distance (i.e. as the crow flies) and the distance by land transport (roads).

For [future reference](https://www.freemaptools.com/how-far-is-it-between-palermo_-italy-and-catania_-italy.htm?units=KM):

[image]